# How long is one generation for a mosquito?

Tags: genetics

For instance, humans are said to have an average generation time of 20 years. I've heard that mosquitos go through 10 generations in a year. Is that information correct?

Comment: This  http://www.mosquito.org/life-cycle  is the first hit if you google "mosquito generation time".  14 days, apparently.

Comment: it's variable depending on the species, temperature, and feeding.

Comment: @Roland I think you can make an answer out of your comment. There will probably be no need to further the answer much more than what the comments currently say.

Comment: I feel the need to add that there are thousands of different mosquito species, but I'm guessing you're mostly interested in the ones that cause humans problems? (These should be the ones that the American Mosquito Control Association talk about, too.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this information page](http://www.mosquito.org/life-cycle) from the American Mosquito Control Association, the generation time for a mosquito at 70${}^\circ$ F is about 14 days. The precise generation time depends on temperature and access to nutrients, but yes, it seems reasonable that mosquitos can go through 10 generations or more in a year.